# Next.js catch-block in a server action does not catch errors thrown in a nested function

Tags: next.js

I've created a server action function that is called when the user presses a button. I have defined a try-catch block at the top level of the server action.
But I've noticed that the catch-block will only catch errors that are thrown directly inside the try-block. If I throw the same error inside a nested function that is also called inside the try-block, the catch-block is not catching it.
Only after the server action finished the error is thrown and print to the console, but nothing more.

Does anyone know why this is and how I can fix this problem?

This is my code:

```
// app/myPage/page.tsx
'use client'

const MyPage = () => {
    const onSubmit = () => {
        serverSubmit()
    }

    // Render submit button that calls onSubmit()
}
```

```
// app/myPage/actions.ts
'use server'

export const serverSubmit = async () => {
    try
    {
        throwError()            // This will not trigger the catch-block
        throw new Error('test') // This will trigger the catch-block
    }
    catch (error)
    {
        // handle error
    }
}

const throwError = () => {
    throw new Error('test')
}
```